# How do I run a formula on filtered data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I use the count formula I get 5 rows (first row is header)
The problem is when I apply a filter to the data, excel still counts all the hidden rows.

For example, lets say I filter out all days except for 2019/11/28 and 2019/11/29.
The count should then only count 2 rows. however, it still counts all the hidden rows resulting in 5.

Any way around this?
Thank you.

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Last, 
2019/11/27, 08:00:00, 3146.99, 3149.84, 3144.77, 3147.44
2019/11/28, 08:00:00, 3145.02, 3149.21, 3142.50, 3148.10
2019/11/29, 08:00:00, 3144.04, 3148.75, 3141.80, 3148.50
2019/12/2, 08:00:00, 3151.17, 3157.81, 3146.32, 3148.27
2019/12/3, 08:00:00, 3117.27, 3121.46, 3096.62, 3097.63
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
=SUBTOTAL(2,A2:A6)
```

or

```
=AGGREGATE(2,3,A2:A6)
```

[image]